# One-way pd.to_numpy inconsistency

Tags: python, pandas

am I missing something, or is this a bug (or features? :) )

I was not able to sensibly copy code and output here - run code below.

In the last part, we change column in df, but nothing changes in the array. So the behavior seems correct (two way) from array to df, and from df to array when it is just one element. However entire row from df to array does not work. Why? Could not find reason, seems dangerous.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create df - index not neccessary, just did it while replicating my non-generic code (nans the same)
index = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', periods=1000, freq='1H', tz='CET')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.ndarray((1000,), dtype=float), 'b': np.ndarray((1000,), dtype=float)}, index=index)
df.loc[:'2019-02-01','a'] = np.nan
# print df
print(df.head(3))
# take numpy view and change it
a = df.to_numpy()
a[:, 0] = 5
# everythin in order
print(df.head(3))
print(a[:3,])
# change 1 item in df
df.iloc[0, 0] = 15
# everything still in order
print(df.head(3))
print(a[:3,])
# change the entire column
df.iloc[:, 0]= 30
# wee - bug?
print(df.head(3))
print(a[:3,])
```

Comment: You shouldn't count on to_numpy being a view of the same underlying array. It may or may not generate a copy of its own (see the official doc), so your idea is dangerous to begin with.

Comment: Like the stated in comments pandas does not promise that it is no copy. In the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) it says under the parameter copy: "Note that copy=False does not ensure that to_numpy() is no-copy." What you do is from my point of view not defined. Which means you can't rely on anything. Maybe someone else can explain the exact reasons. I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Isn't it by definition inconsistent then? Shouldn't copy be always returned? Because same operations on different array may result into different outcomes? For me, this is a definition of bug

Comment: I understand what you mean. But you basically assume a functionality, which do not exist. A Bug would be if the docu says your operations should work.

Comment: You might be right its not supposed to be labeled as a bug, but it is a very weird functionality. I would assume that instead of doing some random stuff under the hood, pandas should force user of to_numpy to use copy=True flag if the copy appears. Otherwise it's seemingly random behaviour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.to_numpy`, you'll notice that it invokes `pandas.core.internals.managers.BlockManager.as_array` unless the `dtype` of the array is homogeneous.

So, when you assign an `int` to an entire column, the underlying storage is not a single homogenous `ndarray` anymore. The first hint is that `df.dtypes` becomes different for `a: int64` and `b: float64`. This activates the `BlockManager.as_array`.

```py
# simpler setup
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5, 2)), columns=list('ab'))

>>> df.dtypes
a    float64
b    float64
dtype: object

>>> vars(df)
{'_is_copy': None,
 '_mgr': BlockManager
 Items: Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
 Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
 FloatBlock: slice(0, 2, 1), 2 x 5, dtype: float64,
 '_item_cache': {},
 '_attrs': {},
 '_flags': <Flags(allows_duplicate_labels=True)>}
```

Then assign an `int` to an entire column:

```py
df.iloc[:, 0] = 30

>>> df.dtypes
a      int64
b    float64
dtype: object

>>> vars(df)
{'_is_copy': None,
 '_mgr': BlockManager
 Items: Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
 Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
 FloatBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: float64
 IntBlock: slice(0, 1, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: int64,
 '_item_cache': {},
 '_attrs': {},
 '_flags': <Flags(allows_duplicate_labels=True)>}
```

Note that `pandas` has evolved a lot recently, especially in the underlying storage (for example to now allow [nullable int array](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)).

As the [docs for `.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) say, the `copy` flag is imperative only if `True` (if `False`, you may still get a copy). One of the reasons why it is the case is the handling of mixed types. More fundamentally, it is that the storage of a `DataFrame` is not always a single homogeneous `ndarray`.

Morale: **do not rely on `df.to_numpy()` to be a view**.

Comment: Thank you for the response and for the explanation how it works under the hood. Still, I think that allowing this behavior in pandas is poor design, so maybe i was incorrect in labeling it as a bug, but it is still something I think should not be present in such large library as pandas...